# React Material Theme Chooser

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I've been working with react material on my application. Everything until now it's fine but I want to make application in which themes can be stored on the back-end and I can load them based on user choice.

So until now, I know I can create multiple themes and store them as stated [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)
but I want to store them to the back-end and I don't have Idea how that would work

So I need help for an idea or some kind of tutorial which can point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can associate a theme entry/id with a profile on your backend, save an entry in your database corresponding for each of your themes (configuration to get it loaded)

Comment: that true but i'm interested what do i store on backend, how do i store them and lets say on load time see id? 
The perfet solution would be probably that i save theme, as css and load it on load time maybe?

Comment: You can for instance start with a simple case, light/dark theme. You've got a table/collection with user_themes in which you set the value of the theme. Then, once you load your app, you get from the database this value to apply the proper theme to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to store the attributes that you are allowing the user to change/specify. For instance, you might only allow them to choose a primary and secondary color. You would then save those two pieces of information in your DB and then recreate the theme using `createMuiTheme`.

Here's some sample code demonstrating this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const themeDB = {
  a: {
    primaryColor: "#0f0",
    secondaryColor: "#f0f"
  },
  b: {
    primaryColor: "#ff0",
    secondaryColor: "#0ff"
  }
};
const createThemeFromThemeDBEntry = themeDBEntry => {
  return createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: themeDBEntry.primaryColor
      },
      secondary: {
        main: themeDBEntry.secondaryColor
      }
    }
  });
};
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentTheme: createMuiTheme() };
  }
  switchToThemeA = () => {
    const themeA = createThemeFromThemeDBEntry(themeDB.a);
    this.setState({ currentTheme: themeA });
  };
  switchToThemeB = () => {
    const themeB = createThemeFromThemeDBEntry(themeDB.b);
    this.setState({ currentTheme: themeB });
  };
  useDefaultTheme = () => {
    this.setState({ currentTheme: createMuiTheme() });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <CssBaseline />
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.state.currentTheme}>
          <AppBar position="static">AppBar using Primary Color</AppBar>
          <AppBar position="static" color="secondary">
            AppBar using Secondary Color
          </AppBar>
          <br />
          <Button
            onClick={this.switchToThemeA}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Use Theme A
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={this.switchToThemeB}
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
          >
            Use Theme B
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.useDefaultTheme} color="secondary">
            Use Default Theme
          </Button>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit oozp6kqkq6]

Comment: So i can do that with createMuiTheme on load time?

Comment: @user3187715 I've added a code example that should clarify this.